# Hibernate Second-Level Cache: Does get use it?

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache, second-level-cache

I've seen it written that the Hibernate second-level cache is only used when invoking the `load` method. I can't find any conclusive answers about whether it's used when calling `get`, which the [GenericDAO](http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/) project we've integrated with uses primarily.

Is the second-level cache used when calling `org.hibernate.Session.get(Class clazz, Serializable id)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, of course it's used by `get`. `Session.load` generates a proxy to the entity, without even checking if the entity exists, so the second-level cache is much more relevant for `get` than for `load`.